# Algorithm to insert a value-string (nodes) in a binary search tree

Tags: c, algorithm, tree, insertion

I’m developing a program for a university exam, the specificity of the problem requires:

1) acquisition by the user of a numeric value n --> done

2) random generation of n integers between 0 and 3n and n strings of 10 characters --> done

3) loading all pairs (number, string) of generated data into a binary search tree algorithm.

4) print on the screen, the data contained in the tree according to a visit order chosen by the user from anticipated, symmetrical and postponed. --> done--> only for int values.

5) screen printing of the data contained in the tree sorted by number key(I’ll try to do it myself before I ask this point).

I already have the algorithm that allows me to insert a value in the tree, but how can I modify the algorithm in such a way that it allows me to acquire a value-string node?

Could you give me some advice?

The software must be written in c language.
I was undecided whether to put all or only a part of the code.

Edit 1)

no, now I will try to list the steps that the software does in order to make everything clearer:
1) the software asks the user to type a valid keyboard value (>0, integer).
2)the software will print on the screen, several random values ranging from 0 to the number entered by the user, multiplied by 3 with n strings of 10 characters (see point 2 of of the examination specifications). e.g if the number entered by the user is 4, the software will print random values between 0 to 12  and for each value, there will be aligned a string composed of  10 random characters.
HERE COMES THE PROBLEM *
the point 3 says: "loading all pairs (number, string) of generated data into a binary search tree algorithm".  * because the point 3 shall be completed before the point 4) in order to be able to apply point 4) correctly. in order to allow the user to choose the visit order, I created a menu (switch). However, at the moment my software is able to apply point 4) only partially, in fact, it prints on the screen only the int values and not the strings, aligned with the int values.

I already know that I have to modify the algorithm of inserting a value in the tree in such a way that the program, in addition to acquiring the values int It also acquires strings. But how can I do that?

[image: point 2) and 4) with only int values]

```
/*Programma contente un albero binario di ricerca che permette all'utente di stampare l'albero nel modo da lui richiesto*/
/*Inclusione librerie*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
/*tree*/

typedef struct  albero_principale /*tree */
{
  int             valore; /* value */
  char            *CARATTERE; /* string */
  struct          albero_principale *sx_p, *dx_p;
} albero_principale_t;


/*function declarations*/
void visita_albero_ant(albero_principale_t *nodo_p); /* visit algorithm in early order */
void visita_albero_simm(albero_principale_t *nodo_p); /* visit algorithm in symmetrical order */
void visita_albero_post(albero_principale_t *nodo_p); /*  visit algorithm in delayed order /* 
albero_principale_t *cerca_in_albero_bin(albero_principale_t *nodo_p, int valore);  /* look for a value in the tree */
int inserisci_in_albero_bin_ric(albero_principale_t **radice_p, int valore); /*insert a value in the tree*/

/*main */
int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
  int num_input, num_casuale, esito_lettura, i, y, val, ordinamento;
  albero_principale_t *nodo, *radice;
  int *ARRAY;
  char *STRINGA;

  srand(time(NULL));  
  radice = NULL;
  ARRAY = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*num_input);
  STRINGA = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*num_input);


  do
    {
      printf("Digitare un input, maggiore di 0, valido: "); /* verify the validation of the input */
      esito_lettura = scanf ("%d",&num_input);
 inserisci_in_albero_bin_ric(&radice, ARRAY[i]);

      if (esito_lettura != 1 || num_input < 0)
           printf("input non valido.\n" );
      while (getchar() != '\n');
    }
    while (esito_lettura != 1 || num_input < 0);


  /*generation of n integers between 0 and 3n and n strings of 10 characters */  
  num_casuale = num_input * 3;
  printf("I valori generati saranno copresi tra 0 e %d. \n", num_casuale);
  for (i = 0 ;(i < num_input); i++)
  {
   ARRAY[i] = rand () % (num_casuale);
   printf("%d ", ARRAY[i]);

   for (y = 0; y < 5; y++)
   {
     STRINGA [y] = printf("%c ",'A'+rand()%('Z'-'A'));
     STRINGA [y+5] = printf("%c ",'a'+rand()%('a'-'z'));
   }
   printf("\n");
  }
   for(i = 0,
      (i < num_input);
      i++);
    {
             inserisci_in_albero_bin_ric(&radice, ARRAY[i]);
             inserisci_in_albero_bin_ric(&radice, STRINGA[i]);
   }



/*Menu that allows the user to choose the visit algorithm*/

  do
   {
    printf("\nI valori doppi saranno sovrapposti.\n");
    printf("Digita 1 per ordinare l'array con il metodo di visita in ordine anticipato\n");
    printf("Digita 2 per ordinare l'array con il metodo di visita in ordine simmetrica\n");
    printf("Digita 3 per ordinare l'array con il metodo di visita in ordine posticipato\n");
    printf("Digita 4 per terminare il programma\n"); /* quit */
    esito_lettura = scanf("%d", &ordinamento);

    switch (ordinamento)
      {

       case 1: printf("Visita anticipata:\n");
       visita_albero_ant(radice);
       break;

       case 2:printf("Visita simmetrica:\n");
       visita_albero_simm(radice);
       break;

       case 3:  printf("Visita posticipata:\n");
       visita_albero_post(radice);
       break;

       default:
       if (esito_lettura != 1 || num_input < 0)
            printf("input non valido.\n" );
       while (getchar() != '\n');
       break;

      }
    }  while(esito_lettura != 1 || ordinamento != 4 );

/*Algoritmo di ricerca
 printf("\nAlgoritmo di ricerca:");
 nodo = cerca_in_albero_bin(radice,val); */  

  return(0);
}

 int inserisci_in_albero_bin_ric(albero_principale_t **radice_p, int valore) /* insert a value in the tree */
{
  int inserito;
  albero_principale_t *nodo_p, *padre_p, *nuovo_p;

  for (nodo_p = padre_p = *radice_p;
    ((nodo_p != NULL) && (nodo_p->valore != valore));
    padre_p = nodo_p, nodo_p = (valore < nodo_p->valore)? nodo_p->sx_p:nodo_p -> dx_p);
  if (nodo_p != NULL)
    inserito = 0;
  else
 {
   inserito = 1;
   nuovo_p = (albero_principale_t *)malloc(sizeof(albero_principale_t));
   nuovo_p->valore = valore;
   nuovo_p->sx_p = nuovo_p->dx_p = NULL;
   if (nodo_p == *radice_p)
    *radice_p = nuovo_p;
   else
    if (valore < padre_p->valore)
      padre_p->sx_p = nuovo_p;
    else
      padre_p->dx_p = nuovo_p;
 }

 return(inserito);
}

/*visit algorithm in early order*/
void visita_albero_ant(albero_principale_t *nodo_p)
{
  if (nodo_p != NULL)
  {
    printf("%d ",nodo_p->valore); /* elabora */
    visita_albero_ant(nodo_p->sx_p);
    visita_albero_ant(nodo_p->dx_p);
  }
}

/*visit algorithm in symmetrical order*/
void visita_albero_simm(albero_principale_t *nodo_p)
  {
    if (nodo_p != NULL)
    {
      visita_albero_simm(nodo_p->sx_p);
      printf("%d ",nodo_p->valore); /* elabora */
      visita_albero_simm(nodo_p->dx_p);
    }
  }

/*visit algorithm in delayed order*/
void visita_albero_post(albero_principale_t *nodo_p)
{
  if (nodo_p != NULL)
  {
    visita_albero_post(nodo_p->sx_p);
    visita_albero_post(nodo_p->dx_p);
    printf("%d ", nodo_p->valore); /* elabora */
  }
}


/*look for a value in the tree*/
albero_principale_t *cerca_in_albero_bin(albero_principale_t *nodo_p, int valore)
{
    albero_principale_t *nodo_ris_p;

    if ((nodo_p == NULL) || (nodo_p->valore == valore))
        nodo_ris_p = nodo_p;
        else
        {
          nodo_ris_p = cerca_in_albero_bin(nodo_p->sx_p,valore);
          if (nodo_ris_p == NULL)
            nodo_ris_p = cerca_in_albero_bin(nodo_p->dx_p, valore);
        }
    return(nodo_ris_p);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'allows me to acquire a value-string node"?  You want to prompt the user to enter a string?

Comment: I modified the question in order to try to make it as clear as possible